# How can I override the WORKSPACE variable in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

In the execute shell I have the following script:

```
ssh -i $SSH_KEY_FILE $SSH_USER@$SERVICE_HOST "/bin/bash" << EOF
  export WORKSPACE=~/my_workspace
  ./script_that_uses_workspace_variable.sh
EOF
```

However, Jenkins seems to propagate its WORKSPACE into the bash shell then override my workspace variable. I've tried a ton of different things but Jenkins keeps on resetting WORKSPACE.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to set custom workspace?
For free style jobs,you should be able to set that from configuration UI.
If you check advanced project option, there is a option for 'use custom workspace' and set the value. Or else you can check advanced option in build section and check if 'use custom workspace' option is there or not.
For pipeline jobs, you can try the ws instruction to set custom workspace.
ws("C:\jenkins") {
echo "jenkins workspace"
}

Comment: We have a script that happens to use a variable called WORKSPACE. I would prefer to change it during the shell execution

Comment: To be clear, I am in machine A which has the correct jenkins workspace. I ssh into machine B which needs a new workspace variable set. For some reason, the ssh shell inherits the workspace and wont allow it to be changed

Comment: Is it taking the value of JENKINS_USER variable from /etc/default/jenkins file in machine B? Can you please try to override this variable?

Comment: I mean value of JENKINS_HOME vaiable not JENKINS_USER.

Comment: Machine B does not have /etc/default/jenkins. I didn't configure it for anything related to Jenkins at all

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [Environment Injector](https://plugins.jenkins.io/envinject/) plugin.

```
[ X ] Prepare an environment for the run
Properties Content [ WORKSPACE=~/my_workspace ]
```

Mind you, WORKSPACE is the Jenkins job workspace (`== ${JENKINS_HOME}/workspace/${ITEM_FULL_NAME}`), so it rather essential; side effects to be investigated.